# Why is tinymce horizontal scroll bar misplaced?

Tags: javascript, html, article

Hello I am doing a retrieve, edit and store system and use TinyMCE 3 as editor.
My problem is that the horizontal scroll bar places itself well below the textarea and actually scrolls the entire html5 article in which the textarea is placed.
The textarea is placed in a container div in order to center it and it works fine. However, I cannot figur out why the horizontal scrollbar is acting as it does. I would have expected it to be placed imediately below the textarea - Is there anyone that can give me a push in the right direction?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>QA-tech Portal</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/all.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//Full featured example from www.tinymce.com/tryit/3_x/full.php
// copy and pasted from abowe URI

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrap700">
    <header>
        <div class="top698">
            <div class="header-l">
            </div>
            <div class="header-c">
                <br><br>
                <a href = "documents/Kom_godt_i_HSE.pdf" target = "_blank">
                HSE System                    </a>
            </div>
            <div class = "header-r">
                &nbsp;<br><br><br><br><br>
                <a href="print_page.php"><img src="../images/print_t_ikon.png" alt="Udskriv" title="Udskriv" width="30" height="30"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
<div id="maina">
<article>
<br><br>
<p>Afsnit:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Arbejdets organisering og dokumentation
<br><br>
Dokument:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;3.2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Organisation og kommunikation
<br><br>Udgave:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Dato:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
2014-02-16&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Skrevet af:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;cgi        <br><br></p>
    <form method = "post" action ="page_append.php">
    <div class="textarea_cont">
    <textarea name="new_doc_contents" style="width:90%; height:400">
     ...here goes text from data base displayed in tinymce......
    </textarea>
    // here I would like the horizontal scroll bar to be
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>Redigeret af: <input type="text" style="width:30px" name="author">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Gem dokument efter
rettelse" class="sbut-green">
    </p>

// here is horizontal scroll bar placed......

    </form>
    <br>
    <br> 
 </article>
</div> <!-- main -->
<div class="clear">
</div>
    <footer>
        //... footer text
    </footer>

</div> <!-- wrap -->
</body>
</html>
```

The footer is not scrolled, as it is not included in the article tag.